# Linq .SingleOrDefault - how to setup a default for a custom class?

Tags: c#, linq

i went over some questions and searched google a bit,
but i couldnt find an answer ( That satisfies me ).

Basicly, i understand the `SingleOrDefault` return null or 0 ( depends on the type ).

but how can i make it return something else ?

`return myChannels.All.Where(_Channel => _Channel.Guid == this.ParentChannelGuid).SingleOrDefault(_SPECIFICCHANNEL);`

so, i want `_SPECIFICCHANNEL` to be returned in case it is not single..
can that be done ?

Comment: Have a look at [SingleOrFallback](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/SingleOrFallback.cs) from [moreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/). By the way, be sure you understand that `SingleOrDefault` throws an exception if there are multiple matches.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be accomplished in a rather simple way. If you create your own extension method that is more specific than the generic `SingleOrDefault`, then the compiler will prefer the more type-specific version. Here's an example that shows how to do that with a simple `Person` class (you can copy-paste it into [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) to quickly see the result):

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name ?? "";
    }
}

public static class PersonExtensionMethod
{
    public static Person SingleOrDefault(this IEnumerable<Person> source)
    {
        var person = Enumerable.SingleOrDefault(source);

        if (person == null)
            return new Person { Name = "Unnamed" };

        return person;
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    var emptyCollection = new Person[0];
    var nonEmptyCollection = new Person[] { new Person { Name = "Jack" } };

    Debug.WriteLine("Empty collection: " + emptyCollection.SingleOrDefault());
    Debug.WriteLine("Non-empty collection: " + nonEmptyCollection.SingleOrDefault());
}
```

In the above example, `SingleOrDefault(IEnumerable<Person>)`, takes precedence over `SingleOrDefault<T>(IEnumerable<T>)` which is less specific.

Comment: That won't work with generic though - it would only work for static typed versions. Plus it won't work with LINQ providers except LINQ-to-Objects

Comment: @Marc. Yes, it will only work when run against a statically-typed reference that is an `IEnumerable<Person>`. But this may fulfill the asker's requirements.

Comment: In my opinion it's not a good idea to change the behavior of a default .net method. If someone were to call SingleOrDefault not knowing that you had written this extension, it could produce really hard to find bugs

Comment: This will not accomplish the caller's "i want _SPECIFICCHANNEL to be returned in case it is not single", it will throw

Answer (score 10):

You will have to make an extension method:

```
    public static T SingleOr<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, T defaultValue) where T : class
    {
        return list.SingleOrDefault() ?? defaultValue;
    }
```

There is no other way. All classes default to null.

Comment: I hate to be nitpicky, but the poster explicitly asked how to do that without their own method, but by changing SingleOrDefault, which you solution does not.

Comment: "There is no other way." - That's a bit dramatic, isn't it? Maybe there's a way you aren't aware of?

Comment: @Allon what I meant is that he will have to write a method or use another one. He cannot change the default value

Comment: @Oskar: He doesn't want to change the default value. He wants to change the value `SingleOrDefault` returns when the collection is empty.

Comment: @Allon Which is default if you do not write another method

Answer (score 5):

Could you use [DefaultIfEmpty()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419.aspx#Y880) (psedo code follows) -

```
return myChannels.All.Where(_Channel => _Channel.Guid == this.ParentChannelGuid).DefaultIfEmpty(_SPECIFICCHANNEL).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: this is a nice idea, but what will happen if i have more then 1 result?

Comment: That is still not the behaviour i need. i need to return the default channel

Answer (score 4):

> *but how can i make it return something else ?*

You cannot. You can make your own method — as shown by Oskar Kjellin — to return someting else, but `SingleOrDefault` will *always* behave as programmed, which means return the default value (`null`, 0) for an item.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use the "??" operator and say

```
return myChannels.SingleOrDefault(_Channel => _Channel.Guid == this.ParentChannelGuid) ??_SPECIFICCHANNEL;
```

Comment: Nice - simple and effective!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define the default value of a type. It is always defined as null for reference types. For structs, it is an instance of the struct where all member fields in turn are set to their default values. For enums, it is always 0 (which may or may not be a defined value of the enum type in question)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Oskar's answer of an extension method you can make that more generic so that it covers value as well as reference types with something like the below:

```
    public static T SingleOrSpecifiedDefault<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Expression<Func<T, bool>> singleOrDefault, T defaultValue) where T : IComparable
    {
        T singleValue = enumerable.SingleOrDefault(singleOrDefault.Compile());
        if (singleValue == null || singleValue.CompareTo(default(T)) == 0)
        {
            return defaultValue;
        }

        return singleValue;
    }
```

This allows you to specify the same LINQ expression that you'd use with `SingleOrDefault` as well as the `defaultValue` (which will be used if no match is found).